# how to change text of a controll but not affect the title of the window ? (or vice versa)

Tags: winapi

I've created a simple window with:

```
CreateWindowExW(
WS_EX_TOPMOST,
L"RichEdit20W",
L"window_text",
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE //...
```

now every time I hange "window text" parameter, both control and window title is changing, the same with `SetWindowTextW()` and `SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, ...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit controls (and rich edit controls) are not really designed to have "titles" as such. It is quite unusual to use a control as a top-level window. Instead, you should register your own window class to use for the top-level window (which can then have its own caption text) and make the edit control a child window.